# Como fazer uma definição múltipla de variáveis em VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, declaração-de-variável

Normalmente programo na web estou me aventurando no VB.net (por livre e espontânea pressão...) e tanto em TypeScript quanto em JavaScript e até mesmo em PHP, tenho o costume de fazer uma definição múltipla de variáveis. Exemplo:

```js
var a, b, c;
// definição singular de dados
a = '';
b = '';
c = '';
// definição múltipla de dados
a = b = c = '';
```

Entendo que não posso comparar diretamente JavaScript com VB.NET porque JS não é uma linguagem fortemente tipada mas, tal definição também funciona no VB. Meu problema é que quando tenho um componente que um atributo dele do tipo `string`, e faço tal declaração, o mesmo me apresenta um valor booleano, assim:

```vb
Public Class Foo
    Public text As String
End Class

Dim a, b, c As New Foo
' definição singular de dados
a.text = ""
b.text = ""
c.text = ""
' definição múltipla de dados
a.text = b.text = c.text = ""
```

Ao meu entender (logicamente falando) a linguagem deveria definir o `c.text` como uma string vazia, em seguida o `b.text` como o valor de `c.text` e ao final fazer o mesmo com `a.text`, sendo assim, como posso fazer um Set múltiplo como no exemplo acima, tendo o mesmo valor para as três variáveis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do jeito que está na sua pergunta, não dá, porque como você mesmo disse não dá para comparar com outros linguagens, mas, existe meios de atribuições que vão funcionar como atribuições iguais para cada instância criada:

```
Dim a, b, c As New Foo With {.text = ""}
```

ou até inicializar a propriedade `.text` com `""` dessa forma:

```
Public Class Foo
    Public text As String = ""
End Class
```

acredito ser as melhores formas de atribuição quando se quer trabalhar com variaveis com o mesmo tipo, mas, eu particularmente gosto de colocar cada declaração separado, mas, nada impede em fazer assim por esse exemplo básico da sua pergunta.

[Funcionando em NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QVookl)

Comment: entendi... bom eu uso isso em casos que em 1 ação eu tenha que alterar vários componentes ao mesmo tempo, ex: 3 inputbox que quando um checkbox estiver marcado, ele vai habilita os 3 (ou seja `inputbox.Enable = true` e se desmarcar ele ja remove os 3.

Comment: @LeandroLuk correto, mas, VB.NET não faz isso, talvez você precise criar métodos ou códigos auxiliares para atribuir dessa forma, igual esta na pergunta realmente não é da linguagem. Quem sabe um dia, eles já colocaram tanta coisa que não precisa ... !!! kkkk

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível fazer isto em VB.NET, o máximo que dá é colocar tudo na mesma linha, mas serão atribuições completamente separadas.

Na verdade quase sempre é algo que não deveria ser feito porque é para economizar digitação e não porque deve ser tudo a mesma coisa, só uma coincidência faz ser a mesma coisa.